# Multiply SQL statements in same document

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Properly a stupid question :-/

I am a little bit in doubt of something. I am starting to have a lot of different documents, where I call a single sql query in. Is there a way, so I can have my sql query in the same document?

Fx:

```
<div class="gamewrapper">
            <div class="todaygametext">
                <p>Todays Game</p>
            </div>
            <div class="todaysgame" id="game">
                <?php include('game.php');?>
            </div>
            <div class="allgametext">
                <p>All Games</p>
            </div>

            <div>
                <?php include('games.php');?>
            </div>

            <div>   
                <form class="gametimeclear" method = "post" action = "delete.php">
                    <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My first include game have this query:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbertable WHERE DATE(numdate) = CURDATE()");
```

My second include games have this query:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM number table;
```

Is there a way where I could have the query in the same document?

Question Update:
These two querys I would like to have in the same document:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbertable WHERE DATE(numdate) = CURDATE()");

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM number table;
```

Comment: show sample data and desire output, right now isnt clear what you want

Comment: Do you mean you want to combine the two results into one?

Comment: I would like that <div1> calls first query, and <div2> calls second query.

Comment: You can have as many queries as you want in a script. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you could put both queries in one file, saving the results in different variables and using those variables in your included PHP files ("game.php" and "games.php").

For example, you could have the following at the top of your script:

```
$todaysGameCount = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbertable WHERE DATE(numdate) = CURDATE()");

$allGames = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM numbertable");
```

However, this can get confusing really fast and can cause bugs that are hard to track; you can't be sure that the variables exist before you use them in the included scripts.
If you want your SQL all in one file, I would recommend creating a class and putting the queries in there, like so:

```
class GameDB 
{

    protected $mysqli;

    public function __construct($mysqli)
    {
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    public function getAllGames()
    {
        return $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM numbertable");
    }

    public function getGameCount()
    {
        return $this->mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbertable WHERE DATE(numdate) = CURDATE()");
    }

}
```

You can then use the class in your include files like:

```
$gameDB = new GameDB($mysqli);

$allGames = $gameDB->getAllGames();
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. This was excat what I was looking for :) Thanks again.